# Magento 2 - Category List Sort by Position with Sub Category Not Working

Tags: magento2, categories

A little background, I'm trying to do a custom Category listing, but at the moment it seems the Category not being sort as I seen on Admin.

Here's the code that I've done so far

```
        $current_store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();

        $root_category_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                    ->setStore($current_store);

        return $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $root_category_id))
                            ->setOrder('position','ASC');
```

And the result, when I tried to echo its ID is like below

```
3
10
4
11
5
7
12
8
15
9
13
14
16
6
```

But, from the Admin, it doesn't reflect the order correctly, below is the figure
[image]

The problem that I realize is, that, I have sub category, I tried to echo the query from above code, and then copy-paste it into sql GUI, and I realize, the position is kinda weird but, it does make-sense, because it's a sub category.
Here's the result when I execute the query on sql GUI
[image]

So, what I tried to achieve is to sort above result, to reflecting what I set on Admin.
Is there anything that I missed? I'm not sure where to look, since I've been stuck around 1-2 days, not sure what's the proper keyword, almost all keyword I did will arrive to **product sort** or kind of that, not **category sort**

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who still needs some answer relating to this question, here's the answer

```
...
            $store_categories = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
            $store_categories = $store_categories->load($this->_root_category_id)->getChildrenCategories();

            foreach ($store_categories as $category) {

                //get id
                $category_id = $category->getId();

                //get category model
                $category = $this->getCategoryModel($category_id);

                $sub_children = $this->getActiveChildCategories($category);

                if (count($sub_children) > 0) {

                    $sub_categories = $this->getSubCategory($sub_children);
                    $categories = array_merge($categories, $sub_categories);

                } else {

                    $categories[] = $category;

                }

            }
...
```

The `_categoryFactory` comes from `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory`.

---

It's pretty much covering what I want, but not really as I expected before, because I think it's not really efficient.

PS - I'm still new on Magento 2, so, if someone else has other answer that might be pretty much like I expect, then, I'm happily change it as Accepted Answer. :)

Goodluck!